# Kubernetes clean slate

Tags: kubernetes

I'm following a kubernetes tutorial. I got halfway through but now I want to start over.

I tried `kubectl delete pods --all --force` but when I do `kubectl get pods` it still shows my deployments, and the age is reset. How do I get back to a pristine state to restart the tutorial?

Comment: you need to delete the deployment, to stop the pods to recreated.

Comment: @sfgroups: Thanks, I used `kubectl delete deployments --all --force --grace-period=0`

Comment: I use https://www.katacoda.com so i don't have to bother with machine setup when i'm trying to learn how to do stuff with K8's :)

Comment: @Jay That's an interesting point about that sort of learning platform in general - on the plus side you learn the core tech faster, but on the negative side, you miss the chance to learn in a real-world environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firt, delete the deployments, so that the `ReplicaSet` won't recreate pods:

```
kubectl delete deployments --all --force --grace-period=0
```

Then, use the `--grace-period` flag:

```
kubectl delete pods <pod> --grace-period=0 --force
```

From the documentation:

> --grace-period int        Period of time in seconds given to the resource to terminate gracefully. Ignored if negative. (default -1)

Answer (score 1):

You need to delete the deployments, not the pods. Otherwise the ReplicaSet from the Deployment will just recreate the PODs (self healing capability).

Answer (score 0):

First delete the deployments, otherwise the pods will be recreated:

```
kubectl delete deployments --all --force --grace-period=0
```